# Selecting relational highchart SVG images with Selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, svg, highcharts

As per the below screenshot I have a bar chart on the left which, when I click on, opens the bar chart on the right.

What this then does is open up another bar graph, and I want to click on an element on that. The problem is that the className is "Highcharts-series-group", the same as the previous element locator I used. I've attached a screenshot below of the option I am trying to select (it's the graph on the right) 
[image: Screenshot 1]

Please see below for the HTML, as I don't think it is clear above

```
<div id="controller-breakdown" class="two-by-two-chart" style="display: block;" data-highcharts-chart="1">
<div id="highcharts-2" class="highcharts-container" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 588px; height: 300px; text-align: left; line-height: normal; z-index: 0; font-family: "Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans Unicode",Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; left: 0.083313px; top: 0.916672px;">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="588" height="300">
        <desc>Created with Highcharts 3.0.4</desc>
        <defs>
        <rect rx="5" ry="5" fill="#FFFFFF" x="0" y="0" width="588" height="300">
        <g class="highcharts-grid" zIndex="1">
        <g class="highcharts-grid" zIndex="1">
        <g class="highcharts-axis" zIndex="2">
        <g class="highcharts-axis" zIndex="2">
        <g class="highcharts-series-group" zIndex="3">
            <g class="highcharts-series highcharts-tracker" visibility="visible" zIndex="0.1" transform="translate(61,51) scale(1 1)" style="cursor:pointer;" clip-path="url(#highcharts-3)">
            <rect fill="#ECB631" x="67.5" y="32.5" width="124" height="183" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" rx="0" ry="0">
            <rect fill="#ECB631" x="325.5" y="118.5" width="124" height="97" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" rx="0" ry="0">
        </g>
        <g class="highcharts-markers" visibility="visible" zIndex="0.1" transform="translate(61,51) scale(1 1)">
        </g>
```

What I am trying to do is locate the parent element (div id='controller-breakdown') and from there drill down to the 'g class="highcharts-series highcharts tracker' so that I can select one of the 'rect' values to click on the bar chart. However, because this is an SVG image I am having issue doing this.  The code I have attempted to write in Selenium is below:

```
    public static void relationalBarChartSelector(InternetExplorerDriver driver)
{
    WebElement parent = driver.findElement(By.id("controller-breakdown"));
    List<WebElement> children = parent.findElements(By.tagName("rect"));
    children.get(0).click();
}
```

Could anyone provide any assistance please?

**ORIGINAL CODE**

**

```
    public static void barChartSelector(InternetExplorerDriver driver)
{
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    WebElement parent = driver.findElement(By.className("highcharts-series-group"));
    List<WebElement> children = parent.findElements(By.tagName("rect"));
    children.get(0).click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will Write the xpath for that particular element and then perform the operation on the WebElement  then it will work.The code Which i am providing is working fine for me.you can try this. If you want to click on every rect tag element then you can use a for loop and pass the incrementing variable in place of 1 which is in rect[1] like rect[i].

```
public static void relationalBarChartSelector(InternetExplorerDriver driver)
{
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='highcharts-2']/svg/defs/g[6]/rect[1]"));
    element.click();
}
```

Comment: Hi Subodh, thanks for your comment. This unfortunately didn't work, but then I realised I didn't re-align the HTML I provided above, correctly. I'm still having problems getting it to run when I change the 'g[6]' to 'g[5]', which I believe it should be. Any ideas?

Comment: As an extra comment, using FirePath, the relativeXPath is:          .//*[@id='highcharts-2']/svg/g[5]/g[1]/rect[1]                        this looks similar to what you have put, but selenium is failing to find the element, allowing me to click on it.

Comment: Write a wait statement for 10 seconds above the driver.findelement(...) statement and try it OR you can try with another xpath "//rect[@width='124' and @height='183']" I think it should work fine.. :)

Comment: Hi Subh, I've tried that and unfortunately it still doesn't work. When I was clicking on the first graph I wrote the code above (title: 'ORIGINAL CODE') which worked.....the problem is that the className I used is not unique, so I think I need something similar for clicking on the 2nd graph. That was why I was thinking drilling down via the 'div id="controller-breakdown"' id would be the way forward, but I can't work out the best way of doing this

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will locate anywhere class "highcharts-series-group"

```
public static void relationalBarChartSelector(InternetExplorerDriver driver)
{
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(
      By.xpath(".//*[@class='highcharts-series-group']"));
    element.click(); 
}
```