# How do I loop through bar graph elements in webdriver?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, webdriver

[Selecting relational highchart SVG images with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27129894/selecting-relational-highchart-svg-images-with-selenium)

I asked the above question recently, whereby I wanted to click on some elements within a highchart in order to complete some functions in my automated tests. I've now got around this but have a further question. In some scenarios I will have 3 bars on the highchart; in others I may have more; or less. The code I have written, it is apparent, is restrictive in that it cannot dynamically handle if there is a change to the number of high charts on a page (I've written the code below):

```
    public static void barChartSelector(InternetExplorerDriver driver)
{
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    WebElement parent = driver.findElement(By.className("highcharts-series-group"));
    List<WebElement> children = parent.findElements(By.tagName("rect"));
    children.get(0).click();
    children.get(1).click();
    children.get(2).click();
    children.get(3).click();
}
```

I know, conceptually, that some kind of looping needs to take place so that if I use the barChartSelector method on a highchart that has 4 elements to click on, the method can loop through and handle this. Similarly, if there is another highchart with only 3 elements on, the code should handle this too. This would just make the code more dynamic and future-proof.

Does anyone have any advice on the best way to implement the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe instead of

```
 List<WebElement> children = parent.findElements(By.tagName("rect"));
    children.get(0).click();
    children.get(1).click();
    children.get(2).click();
    children.get(3).click();
```

you could try

```
List<WebElement> children = parent.findElements(By.tagName("rect"));
for (WebElement cur : children) {
  cur.click();
}
```